# ng-init in angular doesnt work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. Trying to use it to build simple applications,I defined a variable in controller named cuurent , now I want to set the value of the input field like the following :

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="UserName" ng-model="management.regData.name" placeholder="UserName" ng-init="management.regData.name = '{{current.FullName}}'"  required>
        <p class="help-block" ng-show="(!editForm.UserName.$pristine && editForm.UserName.$error.required) || (editForm.$submitted && editForm.UserName.$error.required) ">this field is required</P>
          <p class="help-block" ng-show="regUser.usernameMsg && !editForm.UserName.$error.required && editForm.UserName.$valid">{{ regUser.usernameMsg }}</p>
          <ul ng-show="(!editForm.UserName.$pristine && editForm.UserName.$error.pattern) || (!editForm.UserName.$pristine && editForm.UserName.$error.minlength) || (!editForm.UserName.$pristine && editForm.UserName.$error.maxlength)" class="help-block">
            <li>Must not contain any special characters or spaces</li>
            <li>Must be at least 3 characters but no more than 25</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

the problem is that  ng-init="management.regData.name = '{{current.FullName}}'" doesn't work .
any suggestions ?

Comment: try this `ng-init="management.regData.name = 'current.FullName'"`

Comment: you should avoid using `ng-init` whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the curly brackets and just add it

`ng-init="management.regData.name = current.FullName"`

demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.management={"regData":{"name":""}}
$scope.current = {"FullName":"sample"}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="UserName" ng-model="management.regData.name" placeholder="UserName" ng-init="management.regData.name = current.FullName"  required>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution.@sachila But make sure that current.FullName is not from any API call.If it getting from any promise then might be case like HTML page render first and in ng-init it may be undefined

Comment: Thank you for your reply,unfortunately it doesn't work , I think the problem is that management is the alias name of my controller .

Answer (score 1):

Just use without the expression , remove `{{}}`

```
 ng-init="management.regData.name = current.FullName"
```

Comment: i think single quote around `'current.FullName'` need to remove

Comment: @sachilaranawaka yeah right! answering from mobile :P

Comment: hehe no worries :D

Comment: Thank your for your reply , unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use binding expression`{{}}` inside `ng-init`. Also you need to remove `''` around `current.FullName`.

Change your code form

`ng-init="management.regData.name = '{{current.FullName}}'"`

To

`ng-init="management.regData.name = current.FullName"`

Comment: Thank you for your reply,unfortunately it doesn't work , I think the problem is that management is the alias name of my controller .